# Где находится стандартный шаблон 404 ошибки?

Tags: php, apache, http-status-code-404

Где хранится стандартный шаблон страницы для 404 ошибки на апаче?

По ряду причин, мне не нужен свой собственный шаблон, а нужен именно стандартный.
Из-за mvc структуры и единой точки входа я не могу просто выкинуть 404 ошибку.
Вернее могу, но только самописную, для большинства проектов подходит, но не для текущего.

Подключаю заголовки, а дальше по идее надо просто подключить шаблон. По какому пути он находится?

> header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
>
> header("HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found");

Могу, конечно, сам быстренько его скопировать, ведь там всё просто, но как я понимаю он где-то хранится и изобретать велосипед смысла никакого нет.

Comment: В каталоге апача в `error/HTTP_NOT_FOUND.html.var` посмотрите.

Answer (score 1):

В корневой директории сайта есть файл .htaccess (если нет то создайте его). Вставьте в файл эту строку `ErrorDocument 404 /error404.html` После чего создайте файл error404.html. Вот и все! 404 должен работать.

Comment: Вы меня не поняли. Я знаю как создать альтернативную 404 страницу. Меня интересовал вопрос где хранится дефолтная страница 404 ошибки. Она ведь точно где-то хранится. И ErrorDocument с единой точкой входа не будет работать. Делается ведь в роутинге проверка наличия контроллера.

Comment: Понятно. Какая у тебя ОС ?